# Laravel Form return old value

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using I'm using laravel `5.5` and [laravel collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html) to build my forms.

During validation, to manage errors and putting back the old values, I'm using this kind of code:

```
<div class="@if ($errors->has( $question->title )) has-error @endif">
    {!! Form::label($question->title, $question->title) !!}
    {!! Form::text($question->title, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    @if ($errors->has($question->title)) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first($question->title) }}</p> @endif
</div>
```

And everything is working well. But I'm facing a problem where my `name` attributes contains white spaces.

When the page is displayed my `name` attributes are well writen with white space by example `Are you happy?`

But the validation return error mentioning `Are_you_happy?` so the old values are not putted back and the errors messages are not displayed due to the `_`.

I was thinking of using regex to "sanitize" the values in my forms but the error message will still be `The Are_you_happy? field is required.` So not that good.

Is there any tricks or better ways to proceed?
Or is it just a bad practice to have whitespace?

### More info

This also happen with the dot character `.`, it's is replaced by an `_` during validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bad practice to use white space,but it's not an error.

you can work around your problem changing the output of the error messages.

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-error-messages)

**Specifying Custom Attributes In Language Files**

If you would like the **:attribute** portion of your validation message to be replaced with a custom attribute name, you may specify the custom name in the attributes array of your  resources/lang/xx/validation.php language file:

```
'attributes' => [
    'email' => 'email address',
],
```

in your case

```
 'attributes' => [
        'Are_you_happy' => 'are you happy',
    ],
```

Comment: Finally, I created a new field in database so I have the `title` and the `field`. By using this and editing a bit my form, everything is working well. But thanks for your advice!

Comment: Glad I could help !